# Implement an Objective-C method with light weight generics in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift, generics, swift3

I have to implement this method in a DataSource protocol of an Objective-C library

```
(nullable id<SomeClass>)someMethod;
```

I am trying to implement it in my class in Swift, specifically, the AppDelegate, with what I believe keeps equal the signature

```
extension AppDelegate: LIBDataSource {
    @objc func someMethod<T: SomeClass>() -> T? {
        return nil // temporary
    }
}
```

The problem is that

- As it is, I have a warning and an error. The error says `Method cannot be marked @objc because it has generic parameters` (the warning below is also shown)
- If I remove `@objc`, the warning says `Non-@objc method 'someMethod()' cannot satisfy optional requirement of @objc protocol LIBDataSource`

Is there a way to implement a generic Obj-C method of a Obj-C protocol in Swift? Or do I have to do a separate Objective-C class to accomplish this?

Comment: Objective-C doesn't know anything about generics — it just isn't possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax

```
id<SomeClass>
```

is nothing to do with lightweight generics, it means "any Objective-C class as long as it conforms the *protocol* `SomeClass`". Your method doesn't need to be generic but it does need to return an object that conforms to the `SomeClass` protocol. It's signature should probably be something like

```
func someMethod() -> SomeClass?
```